# Simple Javascript button with DIV elements

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to make it so when a button is pressed a corresponding DIV element is displayed. There is a row of buttons once one is clicked the div element should display text relevant to the button.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style type="text/css">
#sidebar div {background-color: #78a809;display: block;padding: 5px;margin: 15px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;border-top-width: 1px;border-right-width: 1px;border-bottom-width: 3px;border-left-width: 1px;border-top-style: solid;border-right-style: solid;border-bottom-style: solid;border-left-style: solid;border-top-color: #74b807;border-right-color: #74b807;border-bottom-color: #74b807;border-left-color: #74b807;width:120px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;}#sidebar div:hover {background-color: #8ac403;border-bottom-width: 1px;margin-bottom:17px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function toggle(vals) {
var d1=document.getElementById("info_1");
var d2=document.getElementById("info_2");
var d3=document.getElementById("info_3");
var d4=document.getElementById("info_4");
var d5=document.getElementById("info_5");
var d6=document.getElementById("info_6");

if (vals=1) {d1.style.display ="block";d2.style.display ="none";d3.style.display ="none";d4.style.display ="none";d5.style.display ="none";d6.style.display ="none";}
if (vals=2) {d2.style.display ="block";d1.style.display ="none";d3.style.display ="none";d4.style.display ="none";d5.style.display ="none";d6.style.display ="none";}
if (vals=3) {d3.style.display ="block";d2.style.display ="none";d1.style.display ="none";d4.style.display ="none";d5.style.display ="none";d6.style.display ="none";}
if (vals=4) {d4.style.display ="block";d2.style.display ="none";d3.style.display ="none";d1.style.display ="none";d5.style.display ="none";d6.style.display ="none";}
if (vals=5) {d5.style.display ="block";d2.style.display ="none";d3.style.display ="none";d4.style.display ="none";d1.style.display ="none";d6.style.display ="none";}
if (vals=6) {d6.style.display ="block";d2.style.display ="none";d3.style.display ="none";d4.style.display ="none";d5.style.display ="none";d1.style.display ="none";}
}
</script>
<table width="490" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="162" valign="top" id="sidebar">
<div onClick="toggle('1');">Button 1</div>
<div onClick="toggle('2');">Button 2</div>
<div onClick="toggle('3')">Button 3</div>
<div onClick="toggle('4')">Button 4</div>
<div onClick="toggle('5')">Button 5</div>
<div onClick="toggle('6')">Button 6</div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="info_1" style="display:block">Indo Text</div>
<div id="info_2" style="display:none">Indigo Text</div>
<div id="info_3" style="display:none">Bangkok House Text</div>
<div id="info_4" style="display:none">Mr D Text</div>
<div id="info_5" style="display:none">Emporium Text</div>
<div id="info_6" style="display:none">Pacifica Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this not working?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Best tip: forget about id's, use a common class and target elements by index.

Comment: Btw, all your if statements are wrong. `if (vals=1)` will always be true. You need `==`.

Comment: Why write code like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send the following value to the "toggle"-function:

```
toggle('1'); // '1'
```

Javascript get this value as a string, but you check it without a single quote (').

But essentially is, that your're using a single "equal" instead of two. It must be look like:

```
if (vals == '6' ) { /* Do something */ }
```

If you just use one = , the statement return always "true", because the variable "vals" get the value "6". If this operation is successful, which always is successful, a "true" is returned ...

In generel you're script looks like very complicated for a simple taks. You should take a look to librarys like jQuery with built-in functions like toggle(), slidetoggle(), fadetoggle() and other ready-to-use functions :-) ... Try the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Thank you for that, sorry for having such a simple solution. Will do better research next time